# .env not being loaded in test environment in Rails with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, environment-variables

I am using `gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 0.9.0'` to load environment variables into a Rails 4.0.5 app. I have a .env file along with a .env.test. All is working well in development, however when it comes to testing, which I do with rspec, it is failing to set the environment variables.

I have gone into Rails console in testing environment and I can see they are set to nil.

Any tips on how to get dotenv to load in testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dotenv.load(File.expand_path("../../.env.#{Rails.env}", __FILE__))
```

upon researching Paritosh's answer I found that the file needed to specified per environment.

Answer (score 32):

This is a late answer, but for anyone who may find it helpful, add this to `spec_helper.rb`

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('.env')
```

Also, Dotenv.load can accept a list, for example:

```
Dotenv.load(
  '.env.local',
  '.env.test',
  '.env'
)
```

Comment: Key thing to note: variants (i.e. `.env.test`) MUST be before the base `.env`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to testing and I was about to start flipping tables.

Answer (score 5):

If you have test specific environemnt config, You can use `Dotenv.overload` to overwrite other env config. Just add the following to your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`.

```
require "dotenv"
Dotenv.overload ".env.test" 
Dotenv.overload ".env.test.local"
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line in `Dotenv::Railtie.load` in rspec setting or any page in which you want to load dot env file.

Comment: tried adding it to spec_helper.rb and I get this error `load': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)

Comment: ohh, anyway, glad to see that you figure this out.

Comment: I woudn't of without your help paritosh-piplewar cheers for the help.