# Running rails console with .env config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I've got a Rails 4 app that is deployed to Heroku and talks to S3. Access credentials for S3 are stored in ENV variables on Heroku and locally I have a .env file.

When I run the server locally via `heroku local -p 3000`, everything works as it should - files upload to S3 just fine.

When I try to run rails console via `heroku local:run rails console`, I can't find the magic sauce to avoid a key not found error.

What am I missing?

.env

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=BUCKETNAME
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=KEYID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=SECRETKEY
AWS_REGION=REGION
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
...
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

the error stack:

```
heroku local:run rails console
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
/Users/username/Development/rails_application/config/environments/development.rb:48:in `fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError)
  from /Users/username/Development/rails_application/config/environments/development.rb:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
  from /Users/username/Development/rails_application/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  from /Users/username/Development/rails_application/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

From dotenv README

```
# config/application.rb
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

Dotenv::Railtie.load

HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']
```

see here too [.env not being loaded in test environment in Rails with rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823257/env-not-being-loaded-in-test-environment-in-rails-with-rspec)

Answer (score 0):

1. Acces your enviroment variables like this: ENV["AWS_KEY"]
2. Make sure you have the enviroment variables set in the heroku admin panel(the last tab,reveal enviroment varibales), do not push the .env file to the respository as that is a dangerous practive.